# Macbook Air not waking up from Suspend/Sleep with rEFInd boot manager installed

Tags: sleep-wake, startup, unix, efi

Having installed both [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) 0.6.10 (updated to 0.6.11) via its `install.sh` and Ubuntu 13.04 on another partition I can now choose on a MacBook Air to boot either MacOS or Linux.

When running MacOS and closing and soon re-opening the lid, everything is fine, but after a longer time of closed lid, the machine is not waking/starting up. Instead I have to long-press the power button and then press it again to boot the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent Macbook going from `sleep mode` into `standby mode` (dump RAM to SSD) too soon, you could also adjust by changing `pmset`'s `standbydelay` value.

`sudo pmset -g` to check current setting

`sudo pmset -a standbydelay [value]` to update settting

But instead of changing `pmset` configuration (which affects your battery life), try using the original `rEFIt` instead, the installation is as simple as the forked project `rEFInd`, and I no longer experience any wake-up problem on my Macbook Air 5.2 (Mid 2012 version/OS X 10.8)

Reference Links:

http://refit.sourceforge.net/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/295105/refind-breaks-standby-mode-on-macbook-air-5-2/296514

Comment: With rEFIt installed OSX wakes up nicely, and refit offers an entry of the previous installed rEFInd where I can still boot Ubuntu, fine. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exact issue with my MacBook Pro and I have rEFInd installed as well. I resolved the problem disabling the `autopoweroff` option with `pmset`. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91139/why-does-my-mbp-sleep-on-mountain-lion-and-often-not-wake-up/91150#91150).

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to have worked already by resetting SMC.

Comment: Actually not, MBA was on AC power when tested, so it didn't go into Deep Sleep ...