# Cannot alter MBP Power Management Settings

Tags: high-sierra, sleep-wake, power-management, hibernate

I've got this problem where I can't alter some `pmset` values in `Terminal`. 
I can change them, the changes are registered with `pmset -g`, but they are ignored.

Example:

```
pmset acwake 0
```

but Mac still wakes if unplugged.

```
pmset hibernatemode 0
```

but it still hibernates after a few hours of sleep.

I've reset PRAM and NVRAM. I've switched off SIP. I've moved on to pulling my hair out.

Any advice in terms of solutions or diagnostic options would be greatly appreciated.

```
Late 2012 13"MBP
2.9 GHz i7
OSX10.13.2
2 TB Crucial SSD
16 Gb RAM
```

Comment: ok, if it is a daft question please ignore! - are you making these changes as root? or as an "ordinary" user?

Comment: It prompts password verification so, yeah. I'm admin.

Comment: Are you using the `pmset -a` qualifier to change settings for all? NOTE: `-b` - on battery, `-c` - on charger, `-u` - on UPS. `-a` - all circumstances.

Comment: Yes, sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0

Comment: Stop the PRAM, NVRAM or SMC resets and pulling your hair. These methods are a total waste of time in this case .

Comment: Hi, I failed to make `lidwake 0` works, have you solved your problem yet? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I identified a serious problem between power management and sleep states management
in version 10.13.4 of MacOS X (I had regular crashes on sleep and hibernate exit: around 5 times a day, and files modifications lost).

I thoroughly tested 10.3.5 and Apple seems to have fixed many problems.
`standby 1` isn't anymore causing a crash on encrypted filesystem on hybernate exit and on sleep exit,
`acwake 0` is working as expected.

But `lidwake 0` is still not working, thus potentially causing the MacBook Pro overheating in a bag around the lower part of the screen and the upper part of the keyboard.

The `DestroyFVKeyOnStandby 1` isn't yet in the documentation and causes a crash on hibernate exit.

The documentation (`man pmset`) isn't appropriate for the `pmset` command:

- some options aren't documented,
- others aren't behaving as documented.

`pmset -g pslog` is pretty useful to understand this behaviour which is changed without notice and without documentation.

I advise you to download [MacOS X 10.13.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1965)

Now I recovered a MacBook Pro I could use to work.

NB: I didn't tested 10.13.0..3 nor 10.13.6 nor 10.14.... (nothing needed, not yet a free dayfull of work to waste on tests, and no time to spend for an editor who doesn't make a correct documentation).

Comment: Hi, `lidwake 0` is still not working in `10.13.6`. Have you found the solution or workaround yet? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `pmset lidwake 0` is still failing, didn't find any workaround. The documentation is wrong and hiding functions. Please report these bugs to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: Is the apple bugreport only a private report? Not like other services such as github issues or bugzilla etc.? I was about to find an existing bug and simply upvote it, but it seems that I can not access other people's bug reports...

Comment: Exactly. My personnal piece of advice is to advertise its record outside of the Apple information black hole for others to be aware that a problem is duly reported since more than 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the partial answer is this...
[Mountain Lion aggressively hibernates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72889/mountain-lion-aggressively-hibernates?rq=1)

Which is autopoweroff 0 to stop the hibernating (on my rig anyway) but acwake 0 is stil baffling. It seems to be a bug as others are unable to alter this setting from 1 to 0 as is mentioned in the linked thread.